# using 'this' property in jquery to make code reusable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi a have created a code that adds a class when the element comes in view, parallax if you like. however i want the items to come in at different speeds the next slower than the one before. I however cant seem to make this code reusable using the 'this' property so that I don't have to rewrite it for each instance I want to use it.

```
if (!jQuery('#thumbnail-section-1 #thumbnail-preview.thumbnail-preview-fade-in').hasClass("is-showing")) {    
      if(wScroll > $('#thumbnail-section-1').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {

        $('#thumbnail-section-1 #thumbnail-preview.thumbnail-preview-fade-in').each(function(i){

          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#thumbnail-preview.thumbnail-preview-fade-in').eq(i).addClass('is-showing');
          }, (700 * (Math.exp(i * 0.35))) - 700);

          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#thumbnail-section-1 .overlay2 h2').eq(i).addClass('showing');
          }, (700 * (Math.exp(i * 0.35))) - 700);

        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a function and inject the selector

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net. so that we can work in it.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure what that is but the site is www.fabianshamano.com/sites/lodge

Comment: Hi Liam I tried that and it didn't work that's why I need help. I tried
jQuery.fn.scrollIn = function(directionScrollIn) {
   return this.each(function() {
   });
});

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to use `this` since your `.each` call can also pass the current element:

```
var $sect = $('#thumbnail-section-1');
var $sel = $sect.find('#thumbnail-preview.thumbnail-preview-fade-in');
var $h2 = $sect.find('.overlay2 h2');

if (!$sel.hasClass('is-showing')) {

    if (wScroll > $sect.offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {

        $sel.each(function(i, el) {   // <-- here
            var delay = 700 * (Math.exp(i * 0.35) - 1);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).addClass('is-showing');
                $h2.eq(i).addClass('showing');
            }, delay);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response, it's not that the code does not work its just that I want it to be dynamically reusable. The trouble I see in your example is it is still only for elements in #thumbnail-section-1, say I want to use the same code for #thumbnail-section-2  and so on but don't want to rewrite the code each time for each section, I hope that makes sense lol

Comment: @FabianShamano right, and to that end you'll see that the only part that will now need to vary is the very first variable `$sect`, which should hint to you that this could be passed instead as a function parameter.    Your subject line is very misleading...

Comment: sorry if I didn't explain well enough, I will give it a try thanks